# change specific field in file using perl

Tags: bash, perl, file, replace, append

```
perl -i -lape 'BEGIN{ $" = "|"} $F[$COLUMN]=$VALUE if $F[0] eq "$ID";' $FILE
```

So I try to replace inside the file the field that exists in the line with the specific `ID` and at the specific `COLUMN` with the given `VALUE`. When I execute no changes are made inside the file. It's important that I do this with perl (so no awk or sed solutions). I have little experience with perl so elaboration is much appreciated.

```
933|text1|text2|text3  
934|colm1|colm2|colm3
935|line1|line2|line3
```

say value=newValue column=2 and id=934 so the file should look like this

```
933|text1|text2|text3  
934|colm1|newValue|colm3
935|line1|line2|line3
```

Comment: It's unclear (at least to me) what you want to replace with what. Can you please show a few lines of input and the desired output for that particular input?

Comment: It would help if you wrote a program rather than trying a one-liner, which can be very difficult to get right, especially for a beginner. What are `$ID` and `$VALUE`? Perl is treating them as Perl variables, which you haven't defined, so they both work as empty strings. If you meant to use environment variables from the shell then you need `$ENV{ID}` and `$ENV{VALUE}`.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you wrote a program rather than trying a one-liner, which can be very difficult to get right, especially for a beginner.

What are `$COLUMN`, `$ID` and `$VALUE`?

Perl is treating them as Perl variables, which you haven't defined, so they both work as empty strings.

If you meant to use environment variables from the shell then you need `$ENV{COLUMN}`, `$ENV{ID}` and `$ENV{VALUE}`.
Also, your `-p` option prints the value of `$_` after you read each line. Since you don't change that, your code that modifies `@F` has no visible effect

Perhaps this is closer?

```
perl -i -lane 'BEGIN{ $" = "|"} $F[$ENV{COLUMN}] = $ENV{VALUE} if $F[0] eq $ENV{ID}; print "@F";' $FILE
```

I think it's much more readable written like this. Note that I have used the [`Env`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Env) module, which is a quick way to *copy* the a list of environment variables to Perl variables of the same name

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Env qw/ COLUMN VALUE ID /;

our $^I = "";     # Enable in-place editing

while ( <> ) {

    my @fields = split /\|/;

    $fields[$COLUMN] = $VALUE if $fields[0] eq $ID;

    print join('|', @fields), "\n";
}
```

Comment: @JimS Did you set the environment variables Borodin refers to?

Comment: @PerlDuck yes the variables are actually used to store the arguments from the bash command

Comment: @JimS: Did you `export` those variables? They are visible only within your shell script unless you do that. Perhaps you had better show us the full sequence of commands that you're executing.

Comment: @JimS Add the `-w` switch to your one-liner. If the env. vars are set, you should see _no_ `Use of uninitialized value…` warnings.

Comment: @PerlDuck when i added it it emptied the whole file but I didn't get an error at the output

Comment: @Borodin well the program is quite big so I tried to avoid that. In awk I use the -v to make the variables visible. Does such thing exists in perl?

Comment: Okay, looking at your example input data, it seems that it is pipe-separated. A simple `-a` on the Perl command line will split on whitespace, so as it stands each line becomes only a single element of `@F`. You need to add a value for the `-F` option which specifies what pattern to split on, but a pipe is a regex metacharacter so you need to escape it. You would *really* be better off writing a program. I've edited the program in my answer to do this for you.

Comment: Why does your program being big make it difficult to `export` three environment variables?

Comment: @Borodin No I meant that I can't post the full program here because it is big and I thought that `ENV` does the job of exporting.

Comment: I erased the print "@F" and now I am getting the `use of unitinitialized value`... So I guess you are right there is a problem with the variables' scope

Comment: @JimS: try `perl -E 'say for @ENV{qw/ COLUMN VALUE ID /}' to see what is in those elements of `%ENV`. If they are undefined then you will just get three blank lines.